# Double Bootstrap Simple Sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

The source I am using is: http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/simple-sidebar/

I am having trouble making it so that I can have two of these simple sidebars. I am trying to make it so there is one on each side of the page (one on the left and one on the right). Right now, the default is for the sidebar to be on the left side. Each sidebar will be activated by 2 separate buttons.

**Note in

```
< div id="wrapper" >
```

-- change to

```
< div id="wrapper" class="toggled">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add another sidebar to the right by adding the menu in html page and its corresponding styles in the CSS.

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Right - Sidebar -->
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper-right">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <li class="sidebar-brand">
                <a href="#">
                    Right toggle
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Shortcuts</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Overview</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Events</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->
```

**CSS:**

```
#sidebar-wrapper-right {
 z-index: 1000;
 position: fixed;
 right: 250px;
 width: 0;
 height: 100%;
 margin-right: -250px;
 overflow-y: auto;
 background: #000;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
 -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
 transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

Look at the working JS fiddle here: [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/naga2raja/jnrn7tq6/)

Comment: Sorry, I guess I wasn't as clear as I thought. Each sidebar will be activated by 2 separate buttons. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add different style to your side bar in a the sidebar-wrapper class, something like this.

```
#sidebar-wrapper{
margin-left: 80%;// change this for your own properties
left: 20%
}
```